# C++: vector to stringstream

Tags: c++, string, stl, vector, stringstream

I want to know if it is possible to transform a `std::vector` to a `std::stringstream` using generic programming and how can one accomplish such a thing?

Comment: Those seem like wholly unrelated types

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: So I should assign the contents of the vector to the stringstream.

Comment: Please define more what you mean by "transform". What should be inserted into the stringstream? The vector elements? Should they be delimited in some way?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Adapting Brian Neal's comment, the following will only work if the `<<` operator is defined for the object in the `std::vector` (in this example, `std::string`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

 // Dummy std::vector of strings
 std::vector<std::string> sentence;
 sentence.push_back("aa");
 sentence.push_back("ab");

 // Required std::stringstream object
 std::stringstream ss;

 // Populate
 std::copy(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss,"\n"));

 // Display
 std::cout<<ss.str()<<std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 only crux is that copy and ostream_iterator should be qualified with std. :)

Comment: Would you not give the benefit of the doubt that using namespace std was at the start of the method?!!! :)

Comment: Lol, might as well be consistent :)

Comment: No no no!  It must *transform* the vector!

Comment: @Noah: Lol, do you propose a change of basis or a magic potion :) ?

Comment: This fails when the vector's element type has no `operator<<`. I think the OP needs to specify the problem more.

Comment: @David Relihan: I'm sure there were, but it could be confusing. :)

Answer (score 16):

If the vector's element type supports operator<<, something like the following may be an option:

```
std::vector<Foo> v = ...;
std::ostringstream s;
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Foo>(s));
```