# How to convert from stringstream to unsigned char vector and vice versa?

Tags: c++, serialization, stdvector, stringstream, std

I have `std::stringstream ss;`, containing binary data that I want to put into `std::vector<unsigned char> my_vector;`. Then, I want to take `my_vector` and use it to create a new `std::stringstream new_ss` identical to `ss`.

I have tried doing something similar to answers from this question:

[Is there a more efficient way to set a std::vector from a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823264/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-set-a-stdvector-from-a-stream)

and this question:

[C++: vector to stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008094/c-vector-to-stringstream)

ending up with:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(ss),
          std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(),
          std::back_inserter(my_vector));
```

then:

```
std::copy(my_vector.begin(), 
          my_vector.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(new_ss));
```

but `ss` and `new_ss` are not the same. I suspected that the problem might be something to do with ignored whitespace so I tried making the vector in this way instead:

```
    std::string const& s = ss.str();
    my_vector.reserve(s.size());
    my_vector.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
```

but this did not fix the problem.

Any ideas on what could be wrong or advice on a better way to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use `std::ios::binary` to construct the string streams?

Comment: It would help to have a [mcve] and know in what way the strings differ... ("not the same" is not super precise)

Comment: @ stringstreams come from cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(ss) and are the result of serializing an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this will be a fairly efficient method:

```
std::string const test_data = "hello world";

std::stringstream ss(test_data);

// discover size of data in stringstream
auto bof = ss.tellg();
ss.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
auto stream_size = std::size_t(ss.tellg() - bof);
ss.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

// make your vector long enough
std::vector<unsigned char> v(stream_size);

// read directly in
ss.read((char*)v.data(), std::streamsize(v.size()));

// Now put it into a new stream object
std::stringstream new_ss;

// direct write again
new_ss.write((char const*)v.data(), std::streamsize(v.size()));

// check the result is the same as the original data
assert(new_ss.str() == test_data);
```

These could be wrapped up into functions to make them easier:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> to_vector(std::stringstream& ss)
{
    // discover size of data in stream
    ss.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    auto bof = ss.tellg();
    ss.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    auto stream_size = std::size_t(ss.tellg() - bof);
    ss.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // make your vector long enough
    std::vector<unsigned char> v(stream_size);

    // read directly in
    ss.read((char*)v.data(), std::streamsize(v.size()));

    return v;
}

std::stringstream to_stream(std::vector<unsigned char> const& v)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.write((char const*)v.data(), std::streamsize(v.size()));
    return ss;
}

int main()
{
    std::string const test_data = "hello world";

    std::stringstream ss(test_data);

    auto v = to_vector(ss);

    auto new_ss = to_stream(v);

    assert(new_ss.str() == test_data);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `reinterpret_cast<char const*>(v.data())` is preferable w.r.t. `(char const*)v.data()`: makes it more clear we are using this "risky" feature https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/2436175

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::istream_iterator<T>` iterator or `std::ostream_iterator<T>` is bound to not work (in case if input) and just unnecessary slow (in case if output). The problem is that `std::istream_iterator<T>` skips leading whitespace and both iterators giing through the formatted interface which makes various checks which don’t really help.

You could use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` or `std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>`. I’d think that converting via the string interface is more effective, though.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` has an overload constructor that takes a pair of input iterators that define the sequence of contents of the new vector.

```
std::stringstream ss;

// Fill in your stringstream, then:

std::vector<unsigned char> my_vector{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{ss},
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}
};
```